# Sending data to a webserver with GPRS recommendations

Tags: arduino, gprs

Im doing a project for tracking bikes in my school.  Im using a GPS EM406-A for recieving the position and a Arduino UNO with the ATMEGA328 for processing the data. Im OK obtaining the data.

Now i need to send the the position to a webserver and then show it on a webpage using the Google Maps API. I have to use the GPRSBee with the M95 from Quectel [(datasheet)](http://www.acmesystems.it/datasheets/M95_HD_V1.2.pdf) but here is where im really confused.

How do i send the information to the webserver so it get stored in a database? Do you have some recomendations? I know a little bit of ruby so i think that im going to use that for showing the data on the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you have 2 pieces of the puzzle to go:
 1. You need to write some server-side code that you can send your data to. So, for example, a Java servlet. (Did you study java, and server-side programming?) Or maybe some Python? The easiest thing is to google RESTful API programming, and you should find plenty of choice there.
2. Once you have written your server-side APIs, then you need to program the GPRSBee to open a TCP/IP connection to your server, and call your API. There is some good sample code at https://github.com/keestux/GPRSbee/blob/master/GPRSbee.cpp
You have a fair bit of work to do, but keep coming back with questions, especially if you try something, and run into a problem.
Best of luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, im going to read about RESTful programming. If i need to send data from the server to the device (to configure some parameteres) do i need to use other type of server-side code?

Comment: Usually you would not "push" data from the server to your device. What kind of parameters do you have in mind?

Comment: In my device i store 1 position received from the GPS each X positions (for example 1 position each 4). That parameter is what i want to change (so i save power not using the GPRS the whole time). I dont know if i explained it well